# When Condition Method in Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

I am trying to figure how to use When method for my use.

```
When(Func<bool> condition);
```

Another post here has one example of usa of When method

```
var mockedService = new Mock<IFormatProvider>();

mockedService.When(() => DateTime.Now.Hour < 12).Setup(x => x.GetFormat(typeof(string))).Returns(null);
```

What I am trying to do is I have a variable called x. I want to use When method so it performs action only when X is not Null.

for example

```
      mockedService.When(()=> !null x).Returns(x)
      or
      mockedService.When(condition => x).Returns(x);
```

Both of the above lines of code are not working syntex is not correct. 
Any idea how to write it correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You must Setup method to return:

```
mockedService.When(() => null != x)
     .Setup(s => s.GetFormat(It.IsAny<Type>()))
     .Returns(x);
```

Another way:

```
mockedService
     .Setup(s => s.GetFormat(It.Is<Type>(t => x != null)))
     .Returns(x);
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid Setup. Because Returns(x) is another method that writes some values to the files than those values are read to perform Assertions. I believe with Setup it might not work? not sure.

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe you need .Callback() ?